# Can't insert Chinese character into MySQL when I use microsoft's cmd（or powershell）

Tags: mysql, utf-8, cmd, character-encoding

**Status**

[image]

Create table message

[image]

**mysql.ini**

[image]

but insert fail

[image]

I set all places to utf8, but it still doesn't work.

But when I use the graphical interface to insert Chinese character into mysql, I succeeded.

Could you give me some suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, post the code and the console output as text. In any case, you probably need to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8.

Comment: I got it, thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Some Chinese characters require `utf8mb4`; `utf8` is not sufficient.

Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

But the real problem is the encoding:

These two `CHARACTER SETs`: gb2312 and gbk use hex `d6d0c3c4` for '中媚'.  However, I see that the first character matches, but not the second.  I can investigate further if you can paste the Chinese character(s) into your question; I cannot work with images.

(Big5 does not work for either character.)

Meanwhile, try this, it may work better but not perfectly:  After connecting, do `SET NAMES gbk;`; this announces the encoding for the client.

Note:  The encoding for the column does not need to be identical to the encoding for the client.  In the long run, it is best to use `utf8mb4` for columns, regardless of what is used in the client.